# Passing SQL null as a SQL statement parameter value using the PostgreSQL libpqtypes PQputf or PQexecf functions

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, null

My friends,

I desire to use the PostgreSQL libpqtypes library with an existing DB from a C app.

One SQL statement I must execute is an insert to a table with an int column that is nullable. It has a schema that I simplify here down to merely:

```
create table t (
    a int null
);
```

I have been reading the documentation of the libpqtypes PQputf and PQexecf functions, but I see no mention of how to pass SQL null values to parameterized SQL statements!

I do not want to pass the C NULL value because this is an int column and I want the value stored in the DB to be SQL null, not 0. So I do not want to do this:

```
PQexecf(conn, "INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (%int4)", NULL);
```

While I could include null directly when generating the insert SQL statement format string that is passed to PQexecf, I do not desire to do this as sometimes I do have to insert a non null value. So I do not want to do this:

```
PQexecf(conn, "INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (null)");
```

It is my desire and ambition to use one single common format SQL insert statement string when calling PQexecf and just pass in a null parameter value somehow when I do not have a value. I want to do something like this, where SQL_NULL is some way to tell libpqtypes that a SQL null should be inserted into the DB:

```
void insert(int *a) {
    /* Other source codes. */

    PQexecf(conn, "INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (%int4)", a ? *a : SQL_NULL);

    /* Other source codes. */
}
```

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Many, many thank yous!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it's not possible using libpqtypes alone (but then I've never used libpqtypes myself).

A workaround that doesn't require much additional C code would be to pick one value to stand in for "NULL", and use `NULLIF` in the statement to convert it into an SQL NULL:

```
// treat -1 as NULL
PQexecf(conn, "INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (NULLLIF(%int4, -1))", a ? *a : -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `"%null"` built-in type. Search [this page in the documentation](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/man3/pqt-specs.html) for "pqt schema".

```
// doesn't require a variable argument.
PQexecf(conn, "INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (%null)");
```